# Attempting zone transfer with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dns

I want to know how to perform a zone transfer with Ruby, utilizing all the discovered name servers.

My code below is not working. If there's a better way to do this, do tell. I'm familiar with gems like Net::DNS, but I wish to do this as a system command if possible.

User input:

```
# Query domain dns info:
print "[*] Search DNS information for: (ex. rotten.com) "

domain = gets.chomp


# Zone xsfr:

28: puts "\nAttempting zone transfer on #{domain}:"

29: for server in system 'host -t ns' << " #{domain}" do

30: system 'host -l '   << " #{domain} #{server}"

31: end
```

## Error:

```
./z0ne_XSFR.rb:29:in `<main>': undefined method `each' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)
```

Input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) method returns the status of the called command as true/false, not its captured STDOUT like it looks like you want.

I'd suggest using basic backticks to capture the output, and then pass that to String's [`lines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-lines) or [`each_line`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-each_line) to iterate over the results like an array:

```
`cmd`.each_line do |l|
  ... Do something ...
end
```

---

> ...it does not accept the given switches like (-t ns, or -l)

Wrong. Opening IRB and typing:

```
`ls -al`
```

Returns the output of the command as a string.

Comment: How exactly can I trap the output of: system 'host -t ns' << " #{domain}" using backticks. The host command doesnt work using backticks only with system cmd. Correction, it does appear to run the host command, but it does not accept the given switches like (-t ns, or -l)

Comment: Thanks for the update. It appears to work under irb but not via the actual script.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong again. Create a file containing  `puts %x[ls -al]` and run it. `%x` is the alternate way of using backticks. Better yet, do that, then append your little test script and output or error to your question so we can see what you're using and the output.

Comment: tin man Thanks. Still works under irb but not the script. Closing out for now.

Answer (score 1):

A zone transfer is provide by AXFR operation on the DNS.

If you want to do it with command line use DIG:

```
dig -t axfr @ns.of_the_domaine.tld domaine.tld
```

and do `system` or backquoting to capture the output.

More cleanly, but you don't seem to want this issue, you could do it with:

```
 Net::DNS::Resolver
```

using the `axfr` method.

Install the [Net::DNS](http://net-dns.rubyforge.org/classes/Net/DNS/Resolver.html#M000155) gem:

```
 gem install net-dns
```

Warning: your DNS configuration has to allow `axfr` from your solving point, otherwise you need to do it record by record with the `query` or `search` methods,
or at the command line with dig specifying ANY, A, MX, NS, etc. record types.